# dji virtual stick body direction

Tags: dji-sdk

[sketch_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL7kt.jpg)
Drone(DJI) heading in north-east in sketch

if my drone is control with sendvirtualstickcommanddata() in **velocity** and **body** co-ordinate system.

What will be my drone direction?

As of my knowledge ...
+Pitch is South East and
+Roll  is North East

Is this right?

(Sorry,Drone damaged so not able to simulate this,but eager to know)

[DJI_virtual stick_Table_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCimZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting off tracks completely.

Pitch, Roll & Yaw are relative to the body of the aircraft regardless of its compass direction (North, South, East, West).

When using the virtual stick to navigate in the world coordinate system, you need to build a control system (feedback system) and translate objectives into commands.

Basically, monitor the compass value of the aircraft and send commands to get closer to the value that you want. **Yaw commands will be enough to realign to the compass direction that you want.**

It's not something that will fit here so you'll have to dig into it yourself.

For more info on the theory, check out [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory).

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a wonderful article written by DJI that describes the world coordinate systems the aircrafts can use but the article was linked to in the old developer forums (which no longer exist).

Maybe someone has a copy of the article; I believe it will answer your questions.